# Selenide Drag And Drop to some offset position

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, selenide

Is it possible to perform drag&drop action to some offset position in Selenide? I want to drag element to some part of the page. Unfortunately I cannot find the answer on other pages and documentation lacks it too. I wanted to avoid using selenium tools like "Action" class. It necessarily has to be moved to offsetX and offsetY.

```
   Actions dragAndDrop = new Actions(driver); 
   dragAndDrop.dragAndDropBy(element, offsetX, offsetY).perform(); -> I want to replace it with some Selenide tool
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Selenide.actions()` static method.

From Selenide javadoc:

> public static org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions actions()
>   With this method you can use Selenium Actions like described in the AdvancedUserInteractions page.

```
   actions()
    .sendKeys($(By.name("rememberMe")), "John")
    .click($(#rememberMe"))
    .click($(byText("Login")))
    .build()
    .perform();
```